# What's the name of this boat?

Tags: nouns

Is there a more appropriate name for a boat like the one below?

Other than fishing boat, wood boat, rowboat, canoe.

Thank you

[image: fishing boat]

Comment: We in the US call them a *sampan* which is not an English word.

Comment: Hi! This link may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_boat_types

Comment: I would go with *skiff* but the boat in the picture is a very traditional simple fishing boat. In general, a *skiff* is a small, light, shallow-draft boat.

Comment: There are many different kinds of boats that are used only in certain localities and which have been adapted to the needs of those localities.  The names likewise tend to be localized.  It would be quite helpful to know where the picture was taken.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cormorant fisherman, though I'm not certain if it's the traditional cormorant fisherman's boat, which is called an *ubune*.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cormorant_fishing_on_the_Nagara_River for more details.

Comment: *Ubune* is longer and bigger, not shallow-draft also. I think you are right that he is a cormorant fisher though.

Comment: ubune must be Japanese then.  So if the context is in China or Vietnam, then this can't be the right word.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The cormorants definitely have the rings around their necks, so he's a cormorant fisherman for sure.

Answer (score 0):

**Weidling (boat)**

> A weidling is a flat-bottomed boat, with similarities to a punt. The weidling is traditionally constructed from solid wood, although today some boats are also made from plywood, plastic or aluminium. It is usually around 9 or 10 metres (30 or 33 ft) in length. A larger version is known as the langschiff, and is up to 15 metres (49 ft) in length.

**Shikara**

> The shikara is a type of wooden boat found on Dal Lake and other water bodies of Srinagar, Jammu & Kashmir, India. Shikaras are of varied sizes and are used for multiple purposes, including transportation of people. A usual shikara seats half-a-dozen people, with the driver paddling at the rear. Like the Venetian gondolas, they are a cultural symbol of Kashmir. Some shikaras are still used for fishing, harvesting aquatic vegetation (usually for fodder), and transport, while most are covered with tarpaulins and are used by tourists.

**Dory**

> The dory is a small, shallow-draft boat, about 5 to 7 metres or 16 to 23 feet long. It is usually a lightweight boat with high sides, a flat bottom and sharp bows. They are easy to build because of their simple lines. For centuries, dories have been used as traditional fishing boats, both in coastal waters and in the open sea.

**Durham**

> The Durham boat was a large wooden, flat-bottomed, double-ended freight boat which was in use on many of the interior waterways of North America beginning in the middle of the eighteenth century.

**Sandolo**

> The sandolo is a traditional, flat-bottomed Venetian rowing boat designed for the generally shallow waters of the Venetian Lagoon. The plural is sandoli.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-bottomed_boat)

Comment: Any idea which of them is appropriate for the boat in the picture?

Comment: All of these are very similar to the picture displayed(at least as far as I saw the pictures). They are all flat-bottomed boats like the one shown in the picture. You can read the information regarding each of these using the link I've provided.